# Difference in using criteriaquery fetch and createcriteria.setFechMode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate I had defined `@ManyToOne` relationship Lazy.
So I used the following code to fetch desired data.

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria()
        .addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .setFetchMode("unit", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("manufacturer",FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("brand",FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setFetchMode("preferred_supplier",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

This worked fine.
But then I used this code to do the same.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> q = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root o = q.from(Product.class);
o.fetch("unit", JoinType.LEFT);
o.fetch("manufacturer",JoinType.LEFT);
o.fetch("brand",JoinType.LEFT);
o.fetch("preferred_supplier",JoinType.LEFT);
q.select(o);
q.where(cb.equal(o.get("id"), id));
```

The Result was same.
I wanted to know what is the difference and what is the better or recommended approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)

> Hibernate offers an older, legacy `org.hibernate.Criteria` API which should be considered deprecated. No feature development will target those APIs. Eventually, Hibernate-specific Criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`.

So, you should use `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery` instead of outdated `org.hibernate.Criteria`.